# How to get one value from multiple values of one key in Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So, I made this dictionary in python that has my class timetable. So, I created a dictionary for each lesson.

```
friday = {}
friday.setdefault('1st', []).append(8.40) #Chemistry
friday.setdefault('1st', []).append(9.30)
friday.setdefault('2nd', []).append(9.50) #Maths
friday.setdefault('2nd', []).append(10.40)
friday.setdefault('3rd', []).append(11.00) #Geography
friday.setdefault('3rd', []).append(11.50)
friday.setdefault('4th', []).append(12.10) #English
friday.setdefault('4th', []).append(12.50)
friday.setdefault('5th', []).append(14.00) #Physics
friday.setdefault('5th', []).append(14.50)
```

The two values per key (lesson) are the start and end times respectively. So, I want to extract only **one** value, **not two** values from one key. How exactly do I do that?

PS. I'm sort of new with dictionaries, I may have missed it while learning, so if there's any excess code, useless code or an easier way to do it, please go ahead and edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have here a dictionary of strings to *lists*. So if you'd like to get the first value from a given key, you can do:

```
friday['4th'][0]
# or for second value
friday['4th'][1]
```